# Unity: Calling a method from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am completely new to Unity and all other answers I've found for this go over my head.

So far I've run everything from the same script, which is getting very big and messy. Therefore I am trying to learn how to call methods from other scripts.

I have a dropdown menu with the code in one script and I'm trying to call that code from another.

ScriptA:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ChoseLanguage: MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMPro.TMP_Dropdown myDrop;

    DisplayController displayController;

    public void DropdownChooseLanguage()
    {
        if (myDrop.value == 1)
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("chosenLanguage", "Spanish");

        if (myDrop.value == 2)
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("chosenLanguage", "Japanese");

        if (myDrop.value == 3)
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("chosenLanguage", "Korean");

        if (myDrop.value == 4)
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("chosenLanguage", "Icelandic");


        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetString("chosenLanguage"));

        displayController.DropdownSetLanguage();

    }
}
```

The selection code works by itself, and the debug.Log shows that the chosen language is being saved correctly to PlayerPrefs.

The error comes when it tries to read the "`displayController.DropdownChooseLanguage();`" line. (Line 28)

Unity gives this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ChoseLanguage.DropdownChooseLanguage () (at Assets/Scripts/ChoseLanguage.cs:28)
```

Script B

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;

public class DisplayController : MonoBehaviour
{

...

    public void DropdownSetLanguage()
    {
        SetFileName();
        setLanguage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Start();
    }

...
}
```

Earlier, the exact same code from Script A was placed in ScriptB and all the code worked as it should.

This is a very noob question but I have simply just never been able to understand how exactly to access other scripts correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I found a solution to this but I'll keep the question up in case other beginners have the same problem or if anyone has a better solution.

I made the `DisplayController displayController;` into `public DisplayController displayController;` and then dragged the gameobject with the displaycontroller script attached into the slot for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

`DropdownSetLanguage` is `public` and it seems you think you can access it by
creating a `DisplayController` object named `displayController`.

It is ok
about to access a class but, `displayController` should be `null` in this state.
Because you have to assign an initial `DisplayController` to `displayController`
in your first code.

You can add `public` or `[Serializable]` tag in front of
`DisplayController displayController;` in your first code then, you can add
a `GameObject` which has a `DisplayController` script in it in Unity editor.
[accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility)